# How to make text box accept Return key function (used for Browser)

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to make my Text box (or Address bar) accept the Return/Enter key as a form of submitting a search.

Currently I have a button which submits the search, and not the textbox itself.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the front-end code for your form/button?  Are you using jQuery?

Comment: Are you making your own Browser in WinForms (or something else desktop based)?...or actually working in a webpage?

Comment: using WinForms starting from blank.
Code for my search button:
BrowserWindow.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently I have a button which submits the search, and not the
>   textbox itself.

Assuming WinForms, set the [AcceptButton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.acceptbutton(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your **Form** to that Button.  Now when you hit enter the button will be automatically clicked for you:

> Gets or sets the button on the form that is clicked when the user
>   presses the ENTER key.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. At first it didn't work because I had Multi-Line enabled and now it works. Cheers.